# sizeof() for an expression

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof

Can anyone explain me this code:

```
int a[]={1,2,3},b[]={6,7,8},c;

c=sizeof(!a+b);

cout<<c;
```

I'm getting as output: 8. But I don't understand why.

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: What were you expecting in c = sizeof(!a+b); ?

Comment: You're just getting the size of a pointer. Which is 8 bytes on your system.

Comment: It shows that on your platform, a pointer to `int` is 8 chars in size.

Comment: Since the expression hardly makes sense, I wonder what the intention was? Was it to operate on arrays like in Python,Matlab,Haskell whatever?

Answer (score 8):

`a` and `b` in this context *decay* to pointer types.

So the expression `!a+b` is an `int*` type. **We need to go into a little more detail here**: `!a` is actually a `bool` type, and that added to an `int*` type is an `int*` type (think pointer arithmetic following the implicit conversion of the `bool` to an `int`).

`sizeof(int*)` is 8 on your platform.

---

Note: `sizeof` is *always* evaluated at compile-time in C++.

Comment: @gsamaras; I think OP is in a confused state, he expected something else but got some really different answers.

Answer (score 8):

You have to read `sizeof(!a+b);`, from innermost to outermost expression.

1. `a` decays to `int*`.
2. `b` decays to `int*`
3. `!a` is of type `bool`, since the logical NOT operator is applied to
   `a`.
4. `!a+b` is of type `bool + int* --> int + int* --> int*`

So you basically do:

```
sizeof(int*)
```

which is the size of a pointer, which, in your system is equal to 8.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>[I added another answer to discard the upvotes I got for my now deleted answer.]</sub>

There are a few things that are happening here.

The first is that arrays naturally decays to pointers. When an array is passed, as-is, when a pointer is expected it will be equal to a pointer to the arrays first element. In other words, the expression `a` is then equal to `&a[0]`.

The second thing to remember is that boolean values can be implicitly converted to an `int` with value `0` (for `false`) or `1` (for `true`).

The third thing to remember is that about pointer arithmetic, that integers can be added to (or subtracted from) pointers.

The fourth thing to remember is that about [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The expression `!a + b` is equal to `(!a) + b`.

And the last thing to remember is that addition is [*commutative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). I.e. `x + y` is the same as `y + x`.

Putting this all together, `a` decays to a pointer to its first element. Then that pointer is passed to the logical not operator `!` which will turn the expression `!a` into a `bool` value of `false` (since the decayed pointer of `a` is not a null pointer). Then that `false` is converted to the integer `0` which is added to the decayed pointer of `b`. The result is a pointer, pointing to the first element of `b` (`b + 0`).

You then pass this pointer to `sizeof`, and you're apparently on a 64-bit system where the size of a pointer is 64 bits, i.e. eight bytes.

Comment: Almost perfect. Something lacks though: array decays to pointer because they are involved in arithmetic. Otherwise I would expect sizeof(b) to just answer number of elements * sizeof(element)

Answer (score 3):

Expressions as the operand of `sizeof` operator are not evaluated, it determines the size by the type of its operand. The expression `!a+b` is of type `int *` (after the array to pointer conversion), and `sizeof(!a+b)` is giving the size of `int *` on your platform.
Note that, though array as an operand of `sizeof` do not decay to pointer to it's first element, but in the expression `!a+b` (pointer arithmetic) they will.